# Blender no longer remembers textures for UV editing?

Tags: uv-image-editor

**In 2.79 the UV/Image editor remembers which texture I used for UV editing** (per polygon).
[image]

**In 2.93 (probably starting from 2.8) this no longer works**, so I have to select the appropriate texture manually everytime - this is very irritating and it slows down my workflow a lot.
[image]

Is there any way how to get the previous behavior back? I have no problem to use an addon for this if there is any which can do that.

Comment: Are you in Workbench Render engine or solid preview? That might be why you can't see the textures.

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter I want UV editor to remember which one is used for UV editing for specific polygon. This is not about the textures in 3D viewport.

Answer (score 2):

1. Textures are no longer assigned to faces, material are. Make sure a material that uses the texture you want is assigned to your face. The default material with a base color texture will work:

   [image: Image plugged into Base Color socket]
2. There is a pin icon to the right of the image selection widget in the UV editor which pins the currently shown image, instead of having the image follow the selected poly. Make sure it is **off**.